Arcade script to group attribute fields in a PopUp
I have a feature layer of land use zones in AGOL Map Viewer. I want to script the Popups to group by a given header name all the different attribute fields and records that pertain to the selected object. Group 1 header is "Location" I'd like in bold and then under location I'd like the attributes 'county', 'zone', and 'division' listed. Group 2 header I'd like in bold is 'Geometry' and I'd like 'st_area(shape)' and 'st_perimeter(shape)" listed.
Here is my code:
// Define  group headers
var header1 = "Location";
var header2 = "Geometry";

// Create a function to format the attribute data under headers

function formatGroupedData(feature) {

var output = "";

    // Group 1 attributes
    output += header1 + ":\n";
    output += "Attribute 1: " + feature.attributes["county"] + "\n";
    output += "Attribute 2: " + feature.attributes["zone"] + "\n";
    output += "Attribute 3: " + feature.attributes["division"] + "\n";

    // Group 2 attributes
    output += "\n" + header2 + ":\n";
    output += "Attribute 6: " + feature.attributes["st_area(shape)"] + "\n";
    output += "Attribute 6: " + feature.attributes["st_perimeter(shape)"];

    return output;
}

// Call the function to format data
formatGroupedData($feature)

When I run the code I get this error: "Test execution error: Execution error - Key not found - attributes. Verify test data."
However, when I change my code to:
// Define  group headers
var header1 = "Location";
var header2 = "Geometry";

// Create a function to format the attribute data under headers

function formatGroupedData(feature) {

var output = "";

    // Group 1 attributes
    output += header1 + ":\n";
    output += "Attribute 1: " + $feature.county + "\n";
    output += "Attribute 2: " + $feature.zone + "\n";
    output += "Attribute 3: " + $feature.division + "\n";

    // Group 2 attributes
    output += "\n" + header2 + ":\n";
    output += "Attribute 6: " + $feature.st_area + "\n";
    output += "Attribute 6: " + $feature.st_perimeter;

    return output;
}

// Call the function to format data
formatGroupedData($feature)

I still get the same issue:


If you look at the help file sample code for accessing an attribute, do you see the use of feature.attributes[]?

I believe I see the sample code for accessing an attribute (feature.Population). I'm not a coder, I try to parse other people's code to make something happen. So then in my code above should it not be feature.attributes, but instead say feature.county?

New error message suggests the field county does not exist in your dataset?

Can you try updating your code to:
// Define  group headers
var header1 = "Location";
var header2 = "Geometry";

// Create a function to format the attribute data under headers

function formatGroupedData(feature) {

var output = "";

    // Group 1 attributes
    output += header1 + ":\n";
    output += "Attribute 1: " + $feature.county + "\n";
    output += "Attribute 2: " + $feature.zone + "\n";
    output += "Attribute 3: " + $feature.division + "\n";

    // Group 2 attributes
    output += "\n" + header2 + ":\n";
    output += "Attribute 6: " + $feature.st_area + "\n";
    output += "Attribute 6: " + $feature.st_perimeter;

    return output;
}

// Call the function to format data
formatGroupedData($feature)

The $ before feature means that it will return the current record rather than all records.


Thanks for your help. I tried that and still have the same issue (please see above in my original post).

Your 'county' field doesn't exist. Go to your data and check the field name which may be different than the alias. The 'Key not found' error means it looked for a field and that field didn't exist. When you type $feature. you should get a list of available fields.

@Pop see the image at the bottom of my original post that shows how you can select available fields

That was it! Works now, thank you.
